# Boolean algebra simplification complex

Tags: boolean-expression, algebra

A’B(D’ + C’D)’ + B( A + A’CD)’

Trying to simplify the above boolean expression having problems with the apostrophe outside the bracket.

I applied the compliment De Morgans rule and got: A’B(DC+D’) + B(A’A+C’+D’) is this correct?

Comment: It's close.  However what do you think A'A is?  Also check the left half.  There is a minor error there.

Comment: And when you get that fixed, you can still simplify it farther.  Anyway, I think you are on the right track, so just keep working at it.

Comment: so the above is correct then i haven't started to expand the bracket and simplify it yet i just applied the De Morgan's rule for the apostrophe that's outside the bracket.

Comment: The right half is correct.  Re do the left side and see if you can get it

Comment: i cant see the error in the left half

Comment: You did not get there in one step.  Put your steps up and i'll point it out to you

Comment: i just did it in my mind without steps and got  to that. I just looked at the De Morgan's rules and got it

Comment: well then there is your problem. Write it down

Comment: i wrote it down but am not seeing the problem with the right hand side

Comment: Thats because I told you its on the left

Comment: I put the answer in for you.  Avoid doing these things in your head.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra and [math.se] instead of directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looking at the left side we have A'B(D'+C'D)'

A'B(D(C'D)') after applying De Morgan's

A'B(D(C+D')) after applying De Morgan's again

From here you can take back over.  You just forgot the parenthesis

Comment: ok thanks. Now i can expand the bracket from here by multiplying the A'B by whats inside the bracket?

Comment: Yep, but distribute D(C+D') first then do that.

Comment: @Lee Feel free to accept my answer if it helped you :)  Good luck.  And remember write this stuff down next time.

Comment: should i do the same with the brackets for for right hand side. it seems i should do the same for it too.

Comment: Yes.  Use all the laws available to simplify it down as much as you can

Comment: B(A’(A+C’+D’)) so it would look like that instead of what i had up top for it.  You said it was correct but based on what you did for the left hand side i thought it should be the same for the right hand side

Comment: Yep you're right.  The right was incorrect.  But what you have just added here is correct.  Nice work